# find a power series for $f(x)=\ln(x^2+1)$.

Tags: calculus, power-series

(a) Find a power series representation for 
$f(x) = \ln(1 + x)$.

$$f(x) =  \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}x^n}{n}$$

What is the radius of convergence, $R$?

$R = 1$

(b) Use part (a) to find a power series for 
$f(x) = x \ln(1 + x)$.

$$f(x)=\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{\left(-1\right)^n x^n}{n-1}$$

What is the radius of convergence, $R$?

$R = 1$

(c) Use part (a) to find a power series for 
$f(x) = \ln(x^2 + 1).$

$f(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}$ **?? <-- This is the answer I'm having trouble finding out.**

What is the radius of convergence, $R$?

$R = 1$

Comment: Replace $x\rightarrow x^2$ on the expression of (a).

Comment: @Abelois The answers I provided are right. I only need help with (c).

Comment: I mean that to find $f_c(x) = ln(x^2 + 1)$, you only have to calculate $f_a(x^2)$, where $f_a(x)$ is the result of (a).

Answer (score 7):

From (a),
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \ln (1 + x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\left(x^n\right)}{n}.
\end{equation}
Then, (c) becomes
\begin{equation}
\ln (x^2 + 1) = \ln(1 + x^2) = f(x^2) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\left(x^{2n}\right)}{n}.
\end{equation}